# How to see service time in glimpse

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having action method which call 3 service methods. 
I want to see time taken by each service to execute in Glimpse.
Glimpse show only time of action method and view.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to; however, you could use the StopWatch class and start/stop before/after the method, and then send it to the Debug/Trace mechanism, which Glimpse picks up.  A tool like Red Gate has the capability of tracing execution time, which runs while the application does; that intercepts all method calls and gives you execution times...

Comment: If we use stop watch then what is use of glimpse.

Comment: Plenty - EF query analysis, displays of data going over the wire, access to system variables, etc.  This is one feature it cannot do, mainly because the tools that do method analysis really slow down the application because of how integrated with the framework it is.

Comment: I just want to  check the time taken by that service. So i was expecting as Glimpse gives details of action and view, same way i will get for  service method.

Comment: Glimpse give details of requests and responses from the client, it's not specific to method calls per se.